# Android: How to catch Events "App Focus", "App Unfocus"

Tags: android, events

I am trying to handle moments when the application is suspended or put to background and also the event when the application is restored and focused.

I can't seem to find anything on the subject, just event listening on items, not on the whole application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should make all your activities extends from a custom activity that manages onResume()/onPause() methods.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: This is not sufficient, I don't want this event to be called when the Activity is switched to another one.

Comment: May be just put a static boolean field that you update in onResume/onPause (of the super activity) ? I don't think that you will have such a control on the application level.